# Numba support for evaluating Probability Density Functions?

Tags: python, random, distribution, numba

Numba [supports **random sampling** of multiple distributions in numpy](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#numpy-random). However, when we want to evaluate the PDF of a distribution using scipy, numba does not seem to support this:

```
from numba import njit
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

@njit
def quick_pdf(n):
    """
    Return the pdf of a standard normal evaluated at multiple different values

    :type n: int
    :param n: number of iterations / values to evaluate PDF at

    :rtype: numpy.ndarray
    """
    out = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        out[i] = stats.norm().pdf(np.sqrt(i))
    return out

quick_pdf(1000)
>>> TypingError
...
    out[i] = stats.norm().pdf(np.sqrt(i))
    ^
This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.
```

Is there some way to get around this other than manually defining the PDF myself? Sometimes the PDF of the distribution I want to evaluate is quite complicated e.g. t-distribution or beta distribution, so it would be tedious to code these up myself from scratch (especially if they are multivariate).

**EDIT:** I am aware I could evaluate a PDF without using a for loop using pure numpy:

```
x = np.linspace(-2,2,10000) # 10000 evaluation points
pdf_eval = stats.norm().pdf(x)
```

The `quick_pdf` function I give above is only a simple illustration. For my actual use case, a for loop is needed as there are if statements and other issues that are iteration dependent.

Comment: You have to implement them yourself. You can look up the definitions in the scipy source-code. Most of the work, but quite straight forward, would be the wrapping of the scipy.special functions needed for the pdfs. I have linked a example in the comments on your previous question.

Comment: thanks @max9111, i'll make sure to check these out